# How to get data from json response

Tags: json, laravel

target url

```
   function purchasetable(Request $request){
   $material = $request->get('query');
   $unitprice = DB::table('materials')->where('name',$material)->select('unit_price','id')->get();
echo json_encode($unitprice);
```

}

code segment on the view

```
 $('#add-btn').click(function() {
    var material = $('select[name="material"]').val();
    var quantity = $('input[name="qty"]').val();
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    alert(material);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('autocomplete.purchasetable') }}",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            query: material,
            _token: _token
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Console output
[image: console output]

I want to access 'id' and 'unit_price' on my view how can I do that explain me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery and also your response is an array, then you can iterate the array like this

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
   console.log(value.id, value.unit_price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output seems to be an Array of Objects.
Any array value can accessed used the " [] " notation.
Since the array contains objects hence it can be accessed using the " . " operator
hence
`data[0].id` and `data[0].value`will give you the desired result.
[0] -> indicates the array position, which is 0 in this case and 
.id - > indicates the object name you want to access.

Comment: Provide more descriptive answer.